# Doing query with website

Tags: database-design, mongodb, python

I want to create a website and I have a data set of schools locations stored in Mongodb . There will be a search box on my website and when I search for the name of the school, I want to get the coordinates of the school.

How can I apply the query I made on the website to the database. What are the processes returning to the back?

Can you show me a way?

I did research on this but could not find an explanatory narrative. I'm so stuck please help. Thank you.

NOT: I don't have to use Mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged Python so I'm assuming that's the functional language you're using. This entry level tutorial, [Python MongoDB](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_getstarted.asp), should be enough to get you started with connecting to your database with Python. (By the way, MongoDB can certainly handle a basic search, but if you plan to have more structured data or relational type queries, then a RDBMS system might better for you like PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: Thank you @J.D. Can you help me also how I connect my website and Mongodb?